# click method not firing

Tags: jquery

I have a menu which I need to scroll back to top when links are clicked. I have this code.

```
$('a').click(function(){

$('.positionHelper').scrollTo( {top:'-800px', left:'0'}, 0 );

});
```

the code works when just the handler function is run in firebug console, but when I attach the click to a selector it does not work.  The only exception is when I attached it to $('html').click. I, fired

I tested this with many different selectors and none work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your html is generated dynically (after page load) you need to use the `.live` method. Your code would be:

```
$('a').live('click', function(){

$('.positionHelper').scrollTo( {top:'-800px', left:'0'}, 0 );

});
```

Comment: will check this, could very well be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Do you attach the event handler after the DOM is loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() { .... };
});
```

Another plausible cause is that your a-tag is rendered later in the applications lifetime. Thus you would bind it using:

```
$('a').live('click', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wrap your code in the document ready function. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(){  
      $('.positionHelper').scrollTo( {top:'-800px', left:'0'}, 0 ); 
      return false;
  }); 
});
```

Your problem now may be that the DOM is not fully loaded yet, so the click event is not bound to the anchor(s) like you want. Also, you may want to add a return false or a 'prevent default' to make sure the actual url that is specified in the href attribute is not followed by your browser but just your code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding an event to an `a` element, you have to use `preventDefault` to make sure the hyperlink does not occur so there is room for the event to fire.

```
$('a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $('.positionHelper').scrollTo( {top:'-800px', left:'0'}, 0 );

});
```